How to convert between children types when inheriting privately
Consider this piece of C++ code:
template <typename T>
struct Base
{ 
    // data members ...

    // conversion constructors:
    template <typename U>
    Base(const Base<U>& other) : n(other.n) { /* ... */ }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : private Base<T>
{
    // no data members!

    // this would not work because of private inheritance:
    // template <typename U>
    // Derived(const Derived<U>& other) : Base<T>(other) {}

};

What is a good way to implement conversion between different instantiations of Derived?
Obviously, one could make all interfaces friends:
    template <typename U>
    friend struct Derived;

but that seems dangerous and unnecessary. A better way to do it would be:
template <typename T>
struct Derived : private Base<T>
{
    // publicly exposed conversion from Base
    explicit Derived(const Base<T>& other)
        : Base<T>(other) {}

    template <typename U>
    operator Derived<U>() const {
        return static_cast<Derived<U>>(static_cast<Base<U>>(*this));
    }
};

but that also requires expansion of the public interface, which might not be ideal. Is there a better approach in terms of encapsulation?
Here is a simplified example:
#include <iostream>

struct Algorithm
{
  private:
    int n_;

  public:
    Algorithm(int n) : n_(n) {}

    int get() { return n_; }

    [[nodiscard]]
    int square() const {
        return n_ * n_;
    }
};

struct PrettyPrint;

struct RawPrint : private Algorithm
{
    RawPrint(int n) : Algorithm(n) {}

    RawPrint(const PrettyPrint& other);

    void print() { std::cout << Algorithm::square() << std::endl; }
};

struct PrettyPrint : private Algorithm
{
    PrettyPrint(int n) : Algorithm(n) {}

    // error: can't convert `RawPrint` to `Algorithm`
    PrettyPrint(const RawPrint& other) : Algorithm(other) {}

    void print() {
        std::cout << "the square root of " << Algorithm::get() << " is "
                  << Algorithm::square() << std::endl;
    }
};

// error: can't convert `PrettyPrint` to `Algorithm`
RawPrint::RawPrint(const PrettyPrint& other) : Algorithm(other) {}

int main() {
    RawPrint a1{42};
    a1.print();

    // error:
    // PrettyPrint a2{a1};
    // a2.print();

    return 0;
}

NOTE:
Please do not include answers and comments related to runtime polymorphism. I do not need runtime dispatch nor dynamic casts, only static conversions between static types.

You have asked this question already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79094854/how-to-convert-between-children-types-when-inheriting-privately. Instead of posting a new one, please edit an old one. The comments there are useful to your question readers.

You can edit and reopen it.

I cannot. When I try I get blank screen that says: "This post is deleted and cannot be edited."

Ja. Something broken in the site design there: You cannot edit while self-deleted, and this is awesomely dumb. You'll have to undelete, edit while potentially accumulating downvotes, and beg for reopening. At this point you've already lost since you'll have two, low-scored posts slowing down the rate at which you can ask new questions unless you can get one of the two good enough to be a positive contribution.

friend looks like the right solution to me. You want all Dervied instances to be tightly coupled, relying on each other's internal implementation details (a private base class is an internal implementation detail). friend is how you say that it's OK to rely on internal implementation details.

@IgorTandetnik My concern is that it is an overkill. You are granting full access to somebody who only needs to do conversion.

What does private inheritance provide, rather than having a private data member?  It seems to me that private inheritance serves no useful purpose (other than a thought experiment and exercise), and only makes it harder to work with the unnamed private inheritance class instance which is effectively an anonymous member variable.  (There's only an is-a relationship when there is public inheritance.)

@Eljay Yes, in this particular example, the usefulness of private inheritance is not obvious. In a large codebase though, for example, it is very useful for avoiding code duplication and for separation of concerns. As an example, take a look at implementation of std::move_only_function.  At line 66, you`ll see that the implementers did exactly the same; they have split the class into two. It was not necessary but it makes finding your way in the code much nicer. This is just one example.

passkey-idiom, Attorney-Client are modular ways to have partial friendship.
